# How can we set the url for Core PHP based website

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I would like to know how to change this URL:

http://www.example.com/category/test.php

to this URL:

http://www.example.com/category/test/

We don't want to use any file extension in the end of the file name (like .html , .php). Is there any suitable way to edit the url in PHP based website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for are pretty or clean URLs. You can accomplish this using the Apache mod_rewrite module, see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

There are loads of systems (e.g., WordPress, Drupal, Expression Engine, CakePHP, ZendFramework) that implement these for you. If you have a quick look for "Pretty or Clean URL Rewriting" on Google or Bing you should find a load of resources to implement this in a way that is suitable for your project.

This is a pretty easy to follow and to the point article, see http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls/ or http://docforge.com/wiki/Clean_URL

Answer (score 0):

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]